# ajax API call Variable {variable} - How do I change it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I set a variable that is useable through a html page? It needs to be useable in javascript & ajax functions.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/events/{account}/events",
    data: { name: "Marcus", location: "HERE" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "CREATE EVENT Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
    }
```

Everything around the variable {account} can change,but I need to use the same account number through the page. Thanks

Comment: That isn't a valid javascript variable... Looks like some other language might be parsing that before it renders on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build up the URL dynamically, based on each `account` parameter. You could use a small reusable function for that:

```
function createEvent(account, eventData, callback) {
  var url = "/events/" + account + "/events";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: eventData
  }).done(callback);
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
var event = { name: "Marcus", location: "HERE" };

// Get some_account_number from somewhere...
createEvent(some_account_number, event, function(msg) {
  alert( "CREATE EVENT Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```